# "Not all code paths return a value" error

Tags: c#

im trying to edit my code to include methods, but its just not working, every time I change something i get an error code. This time my error code is "not all code paths return a value" and ALL of my variables above where ive put the method are "declared but never used" . I'm sure that i'm not using methods properly and I was wondering if someone might be able to help me. I have tried researching but I cant figure it out.

Here is where I get the error:

```
}

public static int Menu()
        {

//Menu for user to select whether to load file or not.
        Console.WriteLine("");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        switch (input.ToLower())

        {
        case "yes":
        case "maybe":
            Console.WriteLine("Great!");
            break;
        case "no":
            Console.WriteLine("Too bad!");
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("I'm sorry, I don't understand that!");
            break;
        }
```

Comment: You are declaring a method that returns an int and never returning that int.

Answer (score 3):

The method declares that it returns an `int` value:

```
public static int Menu()
```

But nowhere in the method does it return anything.  If it shouldn't return anything, change the declaration to specify that:

```
public static void Menu()
```

Otherwise the compiler would need to ensure that every invocation of the method would result in an `int` (or an exception, which is also a valid exit strategy for a method).  Which means every logical path through the method would need to terminate in a `return` statement which provides an `int` value.

Comment: Great! that works, thanks! but above that it still says my variables are declared but never used, because theyre in another method? Do I need to pass them?

Comment: @penumbra: Well, if you have variables that you don't use then you can (and should) probably just remove them entirely.  There's no point in having unused code hanging around.

Comment: @penumbra if the answer is correct and remove your problem accept it !

Comment: @penumbra: Well, either way, I can't really advise on code that I haven't seen.  If it's a new issue then it may be worth a new question entirely.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the error says "does not exist in the current context", I do need the variables that im using, does that mean i shouldnt be using a method around it?

Comment: Ok I see, I might post a new question then